# How to compare float values in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, awk, floating-point

I need to alert if my load average is more than 10.

I could do it like this if my awk command returned an integer:

```
declare -i MAX_LOAD=10

declare -i L1=`cat /proc/loadavg | awk {'print $1'}`

if [ $L1 -gt $MAX_LOAD ]
then
    echo "Alert"
fi
```

But it returns floating value in L1 (e.g., 2.35).

How can I compare the values in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using awk, perhaps the simplest way is to do the
float comparison within this language as well:

```
MAX_LOAD=10.0
if ! </proc/loadavg awk -vmax_load=$MAX_LOAD '{ exit $1 > max_load }'
then
    echo Alert
fi
```

Note that there is a bit of trickery going on: the `!` operator
reverses the test. This is needed because the boolean expression in
awk and the status code that the `if` construct receives values have
opposite meanings. The `<` is used to direct the file `/proc/loadavg`
into awk's standard input. Calling awk with `-vmax_load=$MAX_LOAD`
sets the awk variable `max_load` to the value of the shell variable
`MAX_LOAD`.

In your particular case, since your MAX_LOAD is an integer, and since
all you are reading the first float from a file, an ad-hoc solution
would be:

```
if [ $(</proc/loadavg cut -f1 -d.) -gt $MAX_LOAD ] ...
```

The call to `cut` will extract the integral part of the first number
in `/proc/loadavg`. The idea breaks down if any of the assumptions
stated above become false, however.

Comment: +1, i would get around the double-quoting requirement with `/proc/loadavg awk -vmax_load=$MAX_LOAD '{ exit $1 > max_load }'`

Comment: @dhag, thanks for the answer. Still I could not understand, what "<" and "-vmax_load" doing exactly?

Comment: @Spike, I updated my answer to explain.